# Application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: exception

I get this exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

from my code:

```
private void Rec_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {

        switch (args.Result.Text)
        {
            case "switch one":
                status.text="Room 1 light switched"; //Error here
                break;
            case "switch two":
                status.text="Room 2 light switched"; //Error here
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: The ResultGenerated event is fired on a worker thread.  So you cannot directly update your UI, you must use Dispatcher.RunAsync().

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your help.